# Spring Integration - Flow process with erro handling

Tags: spring-integration

I'm continuing to study SI and in the same time i'm trying to build an application.

My application flow is this:

1. Read XML file and split each tag
2. **Each tag have define an attribute called "interval", and i need to create a job that will be repeated, according to this value.**
3. When the job execution is terminated, need to invoke a Web Service to store information
4. If WBS invokation fails, try to send info by email

Right now i'm arrived on point one ( :D ) of this flow, now i'm trying to move forward and first check the error handling (point 4 of the flow).

This is the actual configuration that i have and this works fine splitting the tag and then invoking the right `service-activator`:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="it.mypkg" />

<si:poller id="poller" default="true" fixed-delay="1000"/>

<si:channel id="rootChannel" />

<si-xml:xpath-splitter id="mySplitter" input-channel="rootChannel" output-channel="routerChannel" create-documents="true">
    <si-xml:xpath-expression expression="//service" />
</si-xml:xpath-splitter>

<si-xml:xpath-router id="router" input-channel="routerChannel" evaluate-as-string="true">
    <si-xml:xpath-expression expression="concat(name(./node()), 'Channel')" />
</si-xml:xpath-router>

<si:service-activator input-channel="serviceChannel" output-channel="endChannel">
    <bean class="it.mypkg.Service" />
</si:service-activator>
```

The endChannel will need to receive all messages from the several channel (sent by the router) and then invoke the WBS. **Right now i'm jkust creating classes to check if the flow will works or not.**

The remaining part of my applicationContext.xml is this:

```
  <!-- Create a poller that will be used by endChannel -->
<si:poller id="poller" default="true" fixed-delay="1000" error-channel="failedInvocationChannel" />

<!--- take messages from serviceChannel and redirect to endChannel, that is responsable to receive messages from all channels created by the router -->
<si:service-activator input-channel="serviceChannel" output-channel="endChannel">
    <bean class="it.mypkg.Service" />
</si:service-activator>

 <!-- end channel is a queue -->
<si:channel id="endChannel">
    <si:queue capacity="10"/>
</si:channel>

<!-- Messages are taken from the queue.. -->
<si:service-activator input-channel="endChannel">
    <bean class="it.mypkg.Invokator" />
</si:service-activator>

<!-- Service activator that handle the errors on the queue -->
<si:channel id="failedInvocationChannel" />

<si:service-activator input-channel="failedInvocationChannel">
    <bean class="it.mypkg.Resubmitter" />
</si:service-activator>
```

but when i run my application i got this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain#0': Cannot create inner bean 'org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain#0$child#1.handler' of type [org.springframework.integration.config.ServiceActivatorFactoryBean] while setting bean property 'handlers' with key [1]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain#0$child#1.handler': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target object of type [class org.springframework.integration.channel.QueueChannel] has no eligible methods for handling Messages.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:313)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:122)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:382)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:157)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1481)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:838)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:158)
```

I've read a lot and i'm a little bit confused about all the components that can be used... maybe my error is because i'm trying to use components in the wrong way...

EDIT: Configuration updated with error-channel on poller and removed chain to handle the error

Answer (score 1):

```
<si:service-activator ref="endChannel" method="dispatch" />
```

You can't use a ref to a channel in a service activator.

Also, it's better to give elements like chains an `id` so exceptions are easier to debug.

Also, you generally shouldn't be manipulating the `errorChannel` header; it's better to add an `error-channel` to the poller and route the error flow that way.

Comment: I've fixed the ref and gived an id to the chain as you suggested. Now the program compile but my exception isnt catched (program "crash"). To write this code i've used the example provided in github intermedie/errorhandling. Can you please tell me how to add error-channel to the poller ? The flow i've written for you is ok or i'm doing something wrong... ?

Comment: You need to edit your question with your current configuration. `<poller ... error-channel="foo" ... />`.

Comment: I've updaterd the question and now seem to work. When i raise an exception this is handled from Resubmitter that is the class used by service-activator connected to failedInvocationChannel